# How can I arrange the hash as required?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/510/A) here on codeforces. I have to put the hash sign on the even number. If the even number of the line leaves 2 after mod by 4, then I have to print the "#" sign on the last `j` element, otherwise when `j==0`. I have written the code and thought a lot how it could work, but the output is not matched. Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >>b;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=b;j++){
            if(i%2==1){
                cout<<"#";
            }
            else if(i%2==0){
                if(i%4==0){
                    if(j==0){
                        cout<<"#";
                    } else{
                        cout<<".";
                    }
                }

                else if(i%4==2){
                    if(j==b){
                        cout<<"#";
                    }else{
                    cout<<".";
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem in your own words without simply linking to an offsite location.

Comment: "the output is not matched" is not a problem description. Show desired and current output and identify the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You have complicated the inner `if` condition too much and you are checking for things that will never happen. `j ==0` is always false since `j` is starting from `1`. Change the following:

```
if(j==0){
```

To:

```
if(j==1){
```

---

#### Side notes

If you have a nested `if` condition like:

```
   if(i%4==0){
     if(j==1){
```

You can often just simplify this to a single condition:

```
   if(i % 4 == 0 && j == 1){
```

When you want to print just a char, don't print a string. It will be slower:

```
 cout << "#"; //prints a string
 cout << '#'; //prints a char
```

And last but not least, putting spaces in your code sometimes increases readibility:

```
for(int j=1;j<=b;j++){  //bad

for(int j = 1; j <= b; j++) {  //good, easier to read
```